# Inserting data to MySQL from XML

Tags: php, mysql, xml, foreach

I'm trying to retrieve data from XML and insert it in MySQL, but the data keeps repeating or looping, not sure how to fix it.

Here is my PHP script that gets the XML data from via audioscrobbler.com API. (See FULL XML data bellow in the page)

```
$artist = 'metallica';
$title = 'whiskey in the jar';
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=track.getInfo&api_key=$myAPIkey&artist=$artist&track=$title") or die("Error: Cannot create object");

foreach($xml->track->children() as $track => $data){

      $song_album .= $data->title;
      $song_tag = $data->tag->name[0];
      $song_imageURL .= $data->image[2];

  $xml = NULL;

}
```

I'm inserting these values to MySQL and that works, but with **$song_album** and **$song_tag** I'm getting the repeats of the same data over and over, and I can't find a way to only insert the text value once.

This is how the ***song_album*** column looks like in mysql after inserting the a row:

```
 Garage, Inc.Garage, Inc.Garage, Inc.Garage, Inc.Garage, Inc.Garage, Inc.Garage, Inc.Garage, Inc.Garage, Inc.Garage, Inc.Garage, Inc.Garage, Inc.Garage, Inc.
```

Where it should be just:

```
Garage, Inc.
```

And here how the ***song_tag*** column looks like in mysql after inserting the that row:

```
metalmetalmetalmetalmetalmetalmetalmetalmetalmetalmetalmetalmetal
```

Where it should be just:

```
metal
```

Here is the XML raw data:

```
<lfm status="ok">
<track>
<id>1003737</id>
<name>Whiskey in the Jar</name>
<mbid>664ae92a-f25a-4df4-a564-66ee87dff1c8</mbid>
<url>...</url>
<duration>303000</duration>
<streamable fulltrack="0">0</streamable>
<listeners>433263</listeners>
<playcount>3389216</playcount>
<artist>
<name>Metallica</name>
<mbid>65f4f0c5-ef9e-490c-aee3-909e7ae6b2ab</mbid>
<url>http://www.last.fm/music/Metallica</url>
</artist>
<album position="9">
<artist>Metallica</artist>
<title>Garage, Inc.</title>
<mbid/>
<url>http://www.last.fm/music/Metallica/Garage,+Inc.</url>
<image size="small">http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/64s/54059755.png</image>
<image size="medium">http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/126/54059755.png</image>
<image size="large">http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/174s/54059755.png</image>
<image size="extralarge">http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/300x300/54059755.png
</image>
</album>
<toptags>
<tag>
<name>metal</name>
<url>http://www.last.fm/tag/metal</url>
</tag>
<tag>
<name>heavy metal</name>
<url>http://www.last.fm/tag/heavy%20metal</url>
</tag>
<tag>
<name>hard rock</name>
<url>http://www.last.fm/tag/hard%20rock</url>
</tag>
<tag>
<name>rock</name>
<url>http://www.last.fm/tag/rock</url>
</tag>
<tag>
<name>cover</name>
<url>http://www.last.fm/tag/cover</url>
</tag>
</toptags>
<wiki>...</wiki>
</track>
</lfm>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you concatenate strings, I experimented with your code and this seems to be fine. Just removed dots while variable assignment and added mysqli code for personal tests.

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);

// Connect
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'dachi');

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}


$artist = 'metallica';
$title = 'whiskey in the jar';
$xml = simplexml_load_file("test.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");

$song_album = '';
$song_imageURL = '';

foreach($xml->track->children() as $track => $data){
    $song_album = $data->title; // I removed dot here
    $song_tag = $data->tag->name[0];

     // Remove dot if correct (can't understand just form this snippet why you concat)
    $song_imageURL .= $data->image[2];

    $xml = NULL;

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `test` (`test`) VALUES (?)");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $song_album);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
}

?>
```

Also I am not sure if you need those variables that you declare.

Just a note:

if you have `$text = 'dachi';`

And yon then give `$text .= 'boy';`

`$text` then equals to 'dachiboy'

So `.=` is for concatenation, and that is what you were doing in a loop. Assigning album names to the same variable with `.=` thus adding them together.

Comment: I removed the dot and it stopped looping the values, but I get the same song added like 12 times in the mySQL database, and the values are in different rows. How can I insert the data in one row only?. Thanks

Comment: Okay, so if a question is about correctly parsing XML and preparing it for database, then please give a full XML file and describe data that has to go to which mysql table fields. I will be happy to help you out.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just skip the whole loop and just collect the data you need directly? Something like:

```
  $xml = simplexml_load_file("http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=track.getInfo&api_key=$myAPIkey&artist=$artist&track=$title") or die("Error: Cannot create object");

  $song_album = $xml->track->title;
  $song_tag = $xml->track->tag[0]->name;
  $song_imageURL = $xml->track->image[2];
```

Comment: I get no data with this suggestion